# 'To Beckon' to somebody or 'to beckon' somebody

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was reading **Anna Karenina** by **Leo Tolstoy** when I come across a verb that I already don't know.

> .... On top of all this she also wanted to go away because she was dreaming of luring her sister kitty , who was supposed to return from abroad in the middle of summer and had been ordered to bath , to stay with her in the country . kitty had written to her from the spa that nothing **beckoned** (to) her so much as spending the summer together with Dolly in Yergushovo , which for both of them was full of childhood memories.

Having searched this verb in dictionary , I come to understand the meaning of it . but what is still problematic to me is that The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary says that when this verb means `to appear very attractive to somebody` we haven't to bring **to with it **.In other words, we must say simply 'the prospect of a month without was beckoning her'.

So , my question is why the translator has used this verb with
"to" ?
Is this kind of using this verb possible?
Has the translator has made a mistake ?

The text is from **Anna karenina** translated by **Joel Carmichael**

Comment: That's a strange use of beckon. Look at all the examples in the Oxford Dictionary definition 1.2 [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/beckon).

Comment: To appear very attractive to somebody is to summon them **over**, to draw them **in**, to call them or to call **out** to them. These verbal phrases beckon to a translator to add the **to** for rounding out the verb beckon.

Comment: NB _Karenina, Tolstoy_ and _Kitty_ should all have a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

The OP asks: The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary says that when this verb means to appear very attractive to somebody we haven't to bring **to with it **.In other words, we must say simply 'the prospect of a month without was beckoning her'. And therefore whether the translation of Tolstoy that says "nothing beckoned (to) her so much as spending the summer together with Dolly"

The OALD entry is:

[intransitive, transitive]

> to appear very attractive to somebody
>
> The clear blue sea beckoned.
>
> beckon somebody
>
> The prospect of a month without work was beckoning her.

Since beckon is both transitive and intransitive, either way is fine and there's nothing wrong with the translation of Tolstoy, with or without the "to."  An NGram search shows beckon used with a direct object and without one.

Further information:

Beckon can be used in the sense of a gesture to call someone over, or to refer to something that attracts--e.g., space, mountains, in this case spending a summer with someone.

[Definition of beckon (MW)](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20beckon&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

**beckoned; beckoning**

> intransitive verb
>
> 1
>      :  to summon or signal typically with a wave or nod My master beckons.
>      He … beckoned to the other generals to come and stand where he stood. — H. >E. Scudder
>
> 2
>      :  to appear inviting :  attract the frontier beckons
>
> transitive verb
>
> :  to beckon to beckoned us over to their table

[image: Travel Advice on Beckoning]

From a 2007 book, on the use of gestures.

Comment: The question (at least as I understand it) is whether **to** can be used with *beckon* in the 2nd meaning (to appear inviting). Your answer does not address that.

Answer (score 1):

The authors of the Macmillan Dictionary used these words to explain the second meaning of [***beckon***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/beckon):

> 2. if something beckons to you, it is very attractive and you feel you have to do something to get it
>      *A bright future beckoned.*

So this may be not as unusual as it would seem. But it is hard to find additional examples of such use.

Answer (score 0):

Both or either are correct.

"She beckoned me over."

"She beckoned to me to come over."

"She beckoned to me: 'come over'"

Comment: So.Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary hasn't mentioned it .

Comment: @Pedram The dictionary isn't what defines the language.  Who knows why the editors left this out of your dictionary.  Nevertheless, "to beckon s.o." or "to beckon to s.o." are both correct though it seems to me with a subtle difference of meaning where without the use of "to", the speaker is suggestion perhaps an expectation that the one beckoned will follow.  With "to", that suggestion feels weaker.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the meaning of beckon that the OP asks about.

Comment: Yes they asked why "to" was used and I just demonstrated correct use. I don't know a great deal about "why" in English, I only know what's correct.

Comment: Allow me. The comment @Clare does not hint that your answer is wrong. It  suggests that you expand on it to prove not that you are right but that your answer is authoritative. That is what I see as the goal here. Your examples demonstrate common use, a citing will add a dimension of reference for the OP and others with the question, and an explanation of why your answer stands solid will show it has merit (rather than just telling the OP it's correct, which it is.)

Comment: No, the suggestion is that this answer is irrelevant. *Beckon* has two meanings, the question is about one of them and this answer is about the other one.

Comment: While 'She beckoned me over' definitely idiomatic, I don't find a bald 'She beckoned me' to be so. I'd say it's not totally acceptable on the Quirk - Svartvik scale.